# VS Code doesn't continue inputs (Dart)

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I have started learning Dart for 2-3 days, something I have noticed is that when I use replit.com, I can continue getting inputs and outputs, for example in this code:

I have the exact code in VS Code and here:
https://replit.com/@Vonarian/anotherhello?v=1

When I click run and debug in VS Code, I enter the Student I want the name/nick of, and then nothing happens, like only one input and it doesn't bring up anything.
I also have tested different codes and projects and it's the same, works on replit but not in VS Code.
[Not continuing in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vomwz.png)

Comment: What happens if you run the program though a normal command prompt? I have head some stories about the VS Code terminal does have some strange behavior.

Comment: Issue is solved, nvm, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the default mode of running Dart scripts is using the Debug Console so that you can use the REPL. Although you could run the script through the Terminal to solve this, it won't allow you to use the debugging features (like breakpoints, or pausing on exceptions).

You can change the default way of running CLI scripts with the `Dart: CLI Console` setting in VS Code as shown here:

[image: Dart CLI Console settings]

This will set it globally (or if set in the Workspace Settings, just for that workspace). Otherwise, you could add `"console": "terminal",` into a `launch.json` configuration to have it apply only to a specific launch configuration.